# Java JComboBox appearence

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

in my application I have 2 types of `JComboBox`: editable and non-editable.
Here how the editable appears in Windows 7 with Java 7:

[image]

and here's the non editable:

[image]

Is it possible to set white background in the non-editable `JComboBox` ?

Comment: You'll have better luck if you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can play with. Have you tried using a custom renderer?

Comment: All comments are about "disable" but I wrote "non-editable" that means the user cannot write with keyboard inside the `combo box` but can click and view the items...

Answer (score 0):

Just set the background on the non-editable combo. **Note**: The editor for an editable combo is a `JTextField` by default, so that's why that `UIManager` value is used.

Using Java 7 on Windows XP:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;

public class ComboBoxDemo implements Runnable
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new ComboBoxDemo());
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public void run()
  {
    String[] items = new String[]{"", "Apple", "Banana", "Carrot"};

    Color bgColor = UIManager.getColor("TextField.background");

    UIManager.put("ComboBox.selectionBackground",
                  new ColorUIResource(bgColor));

    JComboBox combo1 = new JComboBox(items);
    combo1.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    combo1.setEditable(true);
    combo1.setSelectedIndex(-1);

    JComboBox combo2 = new JComboBox(items);
    combo2.setPrototypeDisplayValue("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    combo2.setEditable(false);
    combo2.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    combo2.setBackground(bgColor);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Container c = frame.getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    c.add(combo1);
    c.add(combo2);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(200, 100);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** added code to remove differences with size and focus color.

Comment: It works for me. You'll need to explain your problem a little better.  What are you seeing that you don't want?  Or, what aren't you seeing that you do want?

Comment: I would like that the combo box non-editable (Relazione 1) looks like the combo box editable (lista cod).

Comment: When I run my demo, they do look the same with respect to their background colors, which is what you asked about in your OP. The only other physical differences I see are (1) they have a different length, which you didn't ask about, and (2) the non-editable combo changes color when focus is gained, which you also didn't ask about.

Comment: It would also help to know what version of Java you are running, on which OS, which Look & Feel, etc.